# Is the approach I have used to find the time complexity correct?

Tags: time-complexity

For the following problem I came up with the following algorithm. I just wondering whether I have calculated the complexity of the algorithm correctly or not.
Problem:
Given a list of integers as input, determine whether or not two integers (not necessarily distinct) in the list have a product k. For example, for k = 12 and list [2,10,5,3,7,4,8], there is a pair, 3 and 4, such that 3×4 = 12.

My solution:
// Imagine A is the list containing integer numbers

```
for(int i=0; i<A.size(); i++)                O(n)
{
  for(int j=i+1; j<A.size()-1; j++)            O(n-1)*O(n-(i+1))
  {
    if(A.get(i) * A.get(j) == K)             O(n-2)*O(n-(i+1))
      return "Success";                      O(1)
  }
}
return "FAILURE";                            O(1)
```

O(n) + O(n-1)*O(n-i-1) + O(n-2)*O(n-i-1)) + 2*O(1) =

O(n) + O(n^2-ni-n) + O(-n+i+1) + O(n^2-ni-n) + O(-2n+2i+2) + 2O(1) =

O(n) + O(n^2) + O(n) + O(n^2) + O(2n) + 2O(2) =

O(n^2)

Apart from my semi-algorithm, is there any more efficient algorithm?

Comment: When you run this, wouldn't you get an index out of bounds error where `i = A.size() - 1` and `j = i + 1 = A.size()`? It otherwise appears correct because you are doing `0 + 1 + 2 + ... + (n - 1)` which if you prove by induction is of the order `n^2` https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WHVOLY9mrJ4

Comment: Yes, you are right. It will throw an error in the mentioned situation. Thanks for pointing it out. Is it correct to use "i" in the complexity, as I have used O(n-(i+1))?

Comment: No, you would not use `i` because `i` has nothing to do with the size of your input. We simply use `i` to denote a changing value. There are `n` elements in your input. You conveniently use `i` to ITERATE over `n` elements for programming purposes. But, in terms of analysis, whether you iterate using `i` or count using `c`, the point is you do some operation `n` times. Example, taking the average of a list with `n` values is `O(n)`. There is no `i` involved. Although, if I were to code it, some intermediate variable I use to iterate over the `n` values probably with have the name `i`

Comment: @Jabari the link you provided is somewhat misleading. The correct calculation wopuld be (n*(n-1))/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break down what your proposed algorithm is essentially doing.

For every index i (s.t 0 ≤ i ≤ n) you compare i to all unique indices j (i ≠ j) to determine whether: `i * j == k`.

An [invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_invariant) for this algorithm would be that at every iteration, the pair {i,j} being compared hasn't been compared before.

This implementation (assuming it compiles and runs without the runtime exceptions mentioned in the comments) makes a total of nC2 comparisons (where nC2 is the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) of n and 2, for choosing all possible unique pairs) and each such comparison would compute at a constant time (O(1)). Note [it can be proven](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/N_Choose_k_is_not_greater_than_n%5Ek) that nCk is not greater than n^k.

So O(nC2) makes for a more accurate upper bound for this algorithm - though by common big O notation this would still be O(n^2) since nC2 = n*(n-1)/2 = (n^2-n)/2 which is still order of n^2.

---

Per your question from the comments:

> Is it correct to use "i" in the complexity, as I have used O(n-(i+1))?

i is a running index, whereas the complexity of your algorithm is **only affected by the size of your sample, n.**

IOW, the total complexity is calculated for all iterations in the algorithm, while i refers to a *specific* iteration. Therefore it is incorrect to use 'i' in your complexity calculations.

---

> Apart from my semi-algorithm, is there any more efficient algorithm?

Your "semi-algorithm" seems to me the most efficient way to go about this. Any comparison-based algorithm would require querying all pairs in the array, which translates to the runtime complexity detailed above. 
Though I have not calculated a lower bound and would be curious to hear if someone knows of a more efficient implementation.

**edit:** The other answer here shows a good solution to this problem which is (generally speaking) more efficient than this one.

Comment: Thank you so much for very comprehensive explanation. There is something I cannot understand. How did you deduce that the algorithm make the nC2 comparisons?

Comment: Oops sorry if I jumped to conclusions. It's basic combinatorics. You are starting with the first item of your array and comparing it to all other elements in the array. Then you move to the second item and compare it to all other items in the array **except for the first one** - meaning all items it wasn't already compared to. You then do this for all items in the array. This is exactly what nC2 is. All possibilities of unique combinations of 2 out of a group of size n (ignoring changes in order). For example: for the group 1,2,3,4: 12, 13, 14, 23, 24, 3,4 is six combinations = 4C2 (for n=4)

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm looks like O(n^2) worst case and O(n*log(n)) average case, because the longer the list is, the more likely the loops will exit before evaluating all n^2 pairs.

An algorithm with O(n) worst case and O(log(n)) average case is possible. In real life it would be less efficient than your algorithm for lists where the factors of K are right at the start or the list is short, and more efficient otherwise. (pseudocode not written in any particular language)

```
var h = new HashSet();
for(int i=0; i<A.size(); i++)
{
  var x = A.get(i);
  if(x%K == 0) // If x is a factor of K
  {
    h.add(x); // Store x in h
    if(h.contains(K/x))
    {
      return "Success";
    }
  }
}
return "FAILURE";
```

HashSet.add and HashSet.contains are O(1) on average (but slower than List.get even though it is also O(1)). For the purpose of this exercise I am assuming they always run in O(1) (which is not strictly true but close enough for government work). I have not accounted for edge cases, such as the list containing a 0.

Comment: An elegant solution! I haven't thought of that! Notice you made a small mistake, however: it is k%x and not x%k. Also, this will require at least O(n) and possibly more than O(n^2) additional space. Another thing to note - since you are using a hash table **all your complexity calculations are average case and not true worst case**.

Comment: Every elegant approach. Thank you so much for sharing.